# How do the getRequestDispatcher() and forward() methods work?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm making a login/registration page using JSP, JSTL, and a Java servlet, and I'm using, in the doPost() method of the servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("message", "invalid login");
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

to alert the user when he enters invalid login credentials from index.jsp.

This works, but I don't know why it works; here are my questions:

1. Why is setAttribute() called on the request object and not the response object?
2. As I understand it, I'm forwarding the request and response objects to index.jsp, but how does a jsp page handle these objects? It's a bunch of html, so is the response object altered so that it includes all the html code of index.jsp?
3. Why is getRequestDispatcher() an instance method? That is, why can't RequestDispatcher objects be created using a constructor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `HttpServletRequest` is passed along until the response is finally handled. That is, when the JSP is being rendered, the request object is still available. This is how you pass arbitrary data throughout the whole request handling process.
2. JSP files are compiled to custom servlets that write the HTML to the response.
3. The `RequestDispatcher` is created from the request because it needs to know about the servlet environment. Otherwise it wouldn't know how to dispatch anything.