# Understanding JSP line of code with getRequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/viewArticles.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

So we get the Dispatcher of the Request, and provide the path. Ok so far. Now we forward to it the `req` and `resp`.

Now I am lost: We get `RequestDispatcher` from this `req` so `RequestDispatcher` is member method of `req`. Then why do we need to `forward` `req` itself to this `RequestDispatcher` anyway? Can't this method just use `this` to access `req`?

I found a question identical to mine but it do not understand the explanation, this is why I am asking again as an absolute servlet beginner.

[How do the getRequestDispatcher() and forward() methods work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603155/how-do-the-getrequestdispatcher-and-forward-methods-work)

Just for clarification, `req` and `resp` are of type `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

From th API deginition, the RequestDispatcher an object that receives requests from the client and sends them to any resource (such as a servlet, HTML file, or JSP file) on the server. The servlet container (aka  Tomcatt) creates the RequestDispatcher object, which is used as a wrapper around a server resource located at a particular path or given by a particular name

The getRequestDispatcher() method is available from the current Request Object or from the current Servlet Context Object  . Use req.getRequestDispatcher(path) for a relative path in the same context, and prefer ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(path) for an absolute path.

Before forwarding you can add parameters Object as attribute with req.setAttribute("key", valueObject ) method to foward parameters server-side . The Request handle the data from the client, you can complete it, and the Response will handle the page, the headers , cookies and so on to the client.

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

There's a hint in the JavaDoc of [RequestDispatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html?is-external=true#getRequestDispatcher-java.lang.String-):

```
The difference between this method and ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String) is that this method can take a relative path.
```

So essentially, you can ask for the RequestDispatcher via the ServletContext, in which case you can only use absolute paths, or you can request it via the ServletRequest, in which case you can use paths relative to that request path.

Comment: So assuming you have 2 requests, you can use getRequestDispatcher from one and forward the other request to it? What are the advantages of this?
Or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: Well, you should look at a RequestDispatcher as a sort of wrapper for a "resource", be it a Servlet, JSP, whatever. You use it to hand over a request to it ("forward") after perhaps putting some attributes on it. I think there is only one per resource (ie. every servlet has a request dispatcher, and when you ask for "give me request dispatcher for path x, you get the dispatcher for the servlet mapped at x).

The methods to get the dispatcher for a particular resource return the same instance, but the one on the ServletContext doesn't allow you to use relative paths.